# StumbleUpon Social Interaction Tracking using Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I have a StumbleUpon  button at the bottom of each page but I can't figure out how to trigger and send a Social Interaction to Google Analytics (Universal). This button is wrapped inside an iframe. Below is the outer code for this block:

```
<iframe id="iframe-stmblpn-widget-1" src="http://badge.stumbleupon.com/badge/embed/1/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcompositesmanufacturingmagazine.com%2F2014%2F08%2Fworlds-largest-carbon-composites-superyacht-launched%2F" style="overflow: hidden; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px none;" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="18" width="74"></iframe>
```

I was able to setup Social Interaction Tracking for Facebook, Twitter and Pinterest but this one is driving me nuts. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But Google Analytics code should be able to track that data automatically which shows up under social interaction section in Google Analytics and in case you wish to integrate your Stumbleupon ID with Google Analytics then you can do the same under the advanced Social account integration section of Google Analytics.

Or In case you use a third party stumbleupon button like Addthis then you export data from the service in form of sheets which you can transfer to Analytics.